# Composer says my PHP is too old but it isn't?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel valet on a new macbook, but I am hitting an issue upon installation.

I am installing it via

```
composer global require laravel/valet
```

Here is the issue:

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/valet[v2.13.0, ..., v2.13.19] require illuminate/container ~5.1|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.8.36].
    - illuminate/container v5.8.36 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/valet ^2.13 -> satisfiable by laravel/valet[v2.13.0, ..., v2.13.19].
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong? My PHP version is 8, its higher than all of the requirements.

Comment: `php --version` returns PHP Version 8.0.0.

Comment: Another cause, one that catches me occasionally (we use WHM/cPanel on several projects), is having another version of PHP on the console than the website is using.

Comment: `illuminate/container v5.8.36 requires php ^7.1.3` - is there anything unclear about this?

Answer (score 3):

The caret symbol (`^`) means "Must match major version number" not "Must be at least this version".

`8.0.0` is greater than 7.1.3, and that is the problem. The software has an explicit dependency on version 7 (presumably because version 8 is still pretty  new and illuminate/container hasn't been tested with and updated for it).

---

Now I'm speculating:

> laravel/valet[v2.13.0, ..., v2.13.19] require illuminate/container ~5.1|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.8.36].

says that it has picked quite an old version of illuminate/container. If you explicitly installed a newer version (like 8.0 which that line says meets the requirements) then it might resolve your problem.